# How to move custom domain from one firebase project to another without downtime?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase project that serves live users through a custom domain. I need to move the custom domain to the new version of application that is running in a different firebase project. If I delete the custom domain and add it in another firebase project, how much time will it take to reflect the change? How do I minimize the downtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checked with Firebase support. This can be done without downtime. Here are their instructions:

> To delete your custom domain from the project, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the Firebase Hosting console for your project, you will see
>    your domain.
> 2. Hover over your domain.
> 3. There's an overflow menu (three vertical dots) on the right. From the overflow menu, select "Delete Domain"
>
> When you delete a domain, we don't immediately remove the domain from
> our backend. This is because most of the time developers are moving
> their domains from one project to another, and this feature allows us
> to re-provisioned the  SSL certificate quicker.

I was able to delete and add the domain to another project without any downtime. Thanks to the firebase team for being so thoughtful.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case anymore, removing a domain caused it to start returning 404

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about moving the custom domain (no user sessions), and making a couple of other assumptions, like: the account used to verify the custom domain belongs to both Firebase projects, and that same account will move the domain, the change should be almost immediate, close to zero downtime. You should give it a try with a test domain, it's pretty straightforward.

If the goal is to have zero downtime, better ask [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) to see if it's doable and how to do it.