# How does oAuth consent screen work, if I move the custom domain from one firebase project to another?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, firebase-hosting

I got the oAuth consent approved from a GCP/Firebase project - say ProjectA. I had the custom domain configured in ProjectA's Firebase hosting, while getting the approval. Now, I have removed the custom domain from ProjectA and added it to another GCP/Firebase project - ProjectB. But, both projects are in my user name/GCP billing account. Will this cause oAuth consent to be invalidated in future?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to delete your custom domain from the project, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Firebase Hosting console for your project, you will see your domain.
2. Hover over your domain.
3. There's an overflow menu (three vertical dots) on the right. From the overflow menu, select "Delete Domain".

You can find related detail on the [How to move custom domain from one firebase project to another without downtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559393/how-to-move-custom-domain-from-one-firebase-project-to-another-without-downtime) page.

Once your custom domain deleted from the project, you can use it for the other project. You'll need to go through the OAuth consent screen approval process again, as it will correspond to another project, different from the initial one.

Comment: I have already deleted the custom domain and added it to another project. But that project already has another oAuth screen. So, I want to keep both oAuth consent screen as it is. My question is will this setup create any problem in the future?

Comment: You'll need to apply again for an OAuth consent screen in the target project.